# how to install python 2.6 on centos 8?

Tags: python

There is no python 2.6.x in centos 8. But I need python 2.6 to install a tool. I download the python 2.6.7 source code and run `./configure`. I got config successfully. Then I run `make`, I got an error `*** ERROR: renaming "dbm" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/dbm.so: undefined symbol: dbm_nextkey`. How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your error. Because the python 2.6.x is too old to be installed. Python 2 had been abandoned on January. I try to install python 2.6.x use `pyenv` on centos 7 and successfully. Maybe you can try it.

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git $HOME/.pyenv
vim $HOME/.bashrc 

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
source $HOME/.bashrc
pyenv install -l
yum -y install patch & pyenv install 2.6.7
pyenv versions
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, sorry for the long link

https://linuxconfig.org/install-python-2-on-redhat-8

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-on-centos-8/%23installing-python-2-on-centos-8&ved=2ahUKEwieoOi_r8LqAhUvyoUKHWcPCoIQygQwA3oECAIQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1B197tR-XZ0sMJDTF9p0Vr&cshid=1594373386822